# Elements not centering using margin: auto

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a couple of buttons within a div container on my page, yet using margin: auto is apparently not working.  Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

**CSS**

```
#finalizeButtons{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#finalizeButtons button{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="finalizeButtons">
    <button id="finalize">Finalize</button>
    <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**Pen**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVGdxG

To prematurely answer the obvious questions.  Yes, the page is declared `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, yes the `finalizebuttons` div is wrapped in a body tag, and yes it's meant to be 100% of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code that will work without touching much to your
original code.

You just adjust your CSS as follows:

```css
#finalizeButtons{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align:center;
}

#finalizeButtons button{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: can you please mark it as accepted answer if your problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

i touch your code and this is the solution:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVGdww
you are  using float to left, then the elements never being centered, and using text-align center to the container
expect it help

```
#finalizeButtons{
                    display: block;
                    margin-top: 5%;
                    width: 90%;
                    height: 35px;
                    background-color: blue;
  text-align:center;
                }

                #finalizeButtons button{
                    display: inline-block;

                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    background-color: red;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxzk6nod/)

It was not getting centered because you have the `float` property.

Replace your CSS with the below given one

```
#finalizeButtons {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

#finalizeButtons button {
  display: inline-block;
  /* float: left; */
  /* margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto; */
  background-color: red;
}
```

I think you are using `float:left` to make them aligned one after the other. That can actually be made using just `display:inline-block` and you already have that.

Now, to make it centered, just add `text-align:center` to the container.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C documentation on automatic margin](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_CSS_layout_model_-_boxes_borders_margins_padding#auto_margins):

> Depending upon the circumstances, provision of an auto value instructs the browser to render a margin according to the value provided in its own stylesheet. However, when such a margin is applied to an element with a meaningful width, an auto margin instead causes all of the available space to be rendered as whitespace.

So you need to provide a "meaninful width" in order for the margin: auto to actually center the element inside its parent.

Here's a solution for your problem, using margin: auto:

HTML:

```
<div id="finalizeButtons">
    <div>
        <button id="finalize">Finalize</button>
        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this to you CSS:

```
#finalizeButtons div {
    width: 130px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ah, so the width can't be dynamic?

Comment: That's correct. I've edited my answer to better explain the concept.